# PHPWord reading HTML input Template is partial emppty

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I would be very grateful for someone help in this. Google search doesn't provide an answer at all.

I'm using PHPWord to read 26 html input fields from a html form. The type of all input fields is 'text'. My .docx template is based on the 'Template.docx' located in the 'Examples' folder and contains the same number of variables using the format ${pattern} and the setValue() method.

My problem is phpWord is just reading half of the input fields and leaves the rest blank or in two cases it just print out the variable ${pattern}.

The template is written in MS Word and because of getting in trouble with MS Word formatting errors a second time in Libreoffice Writer.

The code of the Template.php:

```
<?php

require_once '../PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template_LRX.docx');


// Kundendaten

$document->setValue('kname', $_POST['namekunde']);

$document->setValue('kvorname', $_POST['vorname']);

$document->setValue('kstrasse', $_POST['strasse']);

$document->setValue('kplz', $_POST['plz']);

$document->setValue('kort', $_POST['ort']);

$document->setValue('kemail', $_POST['emailkunde']);


// Daten für die Berechnung

$document->setValue('beguenstigt', $_POST['beguenstigter']);

$document->setValue('kgebdat', $_POST['d1'] . $_POST['m1'] . $_POST['y1']);

$document->setValue('klebenserwartung', $_POST['lebenserwartung']);

$document->setValue('kimmo', $_POST['immobilie']);

$document->setValue('kimmowert', $_POST['verkaufspreis'] . 'Euro');

$document->setValue('ksabschlag', $_POST['sabschlag'] . '%');

$document->setValue('kanzahlung', $_POST['anzahlung'] . 'Euro');

$document->setValue('kmiete', $_POST['mietzins'] . 'Euro');


// Ergebnis

$document->setValue('lrlaufzeit', $_POST['lebenserwartung']);

$document->setValue('wertimmo', $_POST['immowert']);

$document->setValue('lrsa', $_POST['sicherheitsabschlag']);

$document->setValue('lrwohnrecht', $_POST['wertwohnrecht']);

$document->setValue('lranzahlung', $_POST['ausgabeanzahlung']);

$document->setValue('lrbasis', $_POST['basis']);

$document->setValue('lrjrente', $_POST['jleibrente']);

$document->setValue('lrmrente', $_POST['mleibrente']);


// Berater

$document->setValue('bname', $_POST['nameberater']);

$document->setValue('btelefon', $_POST['telefon']);

$document->setValue('datum', $_POST['datum']);


// Verarbeitung

$document->save('Leibrentenberechnung.docx');

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Leibrentenberechnung.docx"');

readfile('Leibrentenberechnung.docx');

?>
```